# If a cybercrime were committed while the attacker is on an aircraft, who has the jurisdiction?

Tags: international, jurisdiction, aviation

Say, the plane is flying from country A to B. A cybercrime was committed while the plane was above country C. The attacker hacked into country D. Who has the jurisdiction in this case?

Comment: What country of registry is the plane?

Comment: Your question is different, but [this one](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/which-state-has-jurisdiction-in-a-case-of-a-murder-in-an-airplane/1287#1287) has some relevant background

Comment: An American citizen is on a British Airways airplane registered out of Norway flying from Sydney to Hong Kong, and is over international waters when he hacks into a server in Russia.  Who has jurisdiction?

Answer (score 1):

Any or all of A, B, C & D as well as the country of registration of the plane and the country of which the perpetrator and victims were citizens or residents. In addition, there are sub-national jurisdictions (states, provinces etc.) that may be involved.

Just because one jurisdiction has jurisdiction it doesn't mean that others don't also have jurisdiction.